# How to automatically compile linked libraries in CMake when building an executable?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I am given several projects (git repos) and each of them depends on a number of libraries (also git repos). Every project has just one target executable and links libraries from other repos.

My file structure:

```
├── libraries
│   ├── libraryX (git:master)
│   │   ├── build
│   │   │   └── libX.so
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── fileX.cpp
│   │   └── fileX.h
│   ├── libraryY (git:master)
│   │   ├── build
│   │   │   └── libY.so
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── fileY.cpp
│   │   └── fileY.h
│   └── libraryZ (git:master)
│       ├── build
│       │   └── libZ.so
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── fileZ.cpp
│       └── fileZ.h
└── projects
    ├── projectA (git:master)
    │   ├── build
    │   │   └── outA
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── mainA.cpp
    └── projectB (git:master)
        ├── build
        │   └── outB
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── mainB.cpp
```

This is an example `CMakeLists.txt` file inside `libraryX`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(libraryX LANGUAGES CXX)

set(libraries $ENV{LIBRARIES})
set(projects $ENV{PROJECTS})

add_library(libX SHARED fileX.cpp)

target_include_directories(libX PUBLIC ${libraries}/libraryX/)
```

Currently I am building every library manually, which generates `*.so` files and then I go to the project and build the executable. This is an example `CMakeLists.txt` from inside `projectA`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(projectA LANGUAGES CXX)

set(libraries $ENV{LIBRARIES})
set(projects $ENV{PROJECTS})

add_executable(outA mainA.cpp)

target_include_directories(outA
    PUBLIC
        ${libraries}/libraryX/
        ${libraries}/libraryY/
        ${libraries}/libraryZ/
        ${projects}/projectA/
)

target_link_libraries(outA
        ${libraries}/libraryX/build/libX.so
        ${libraries}/libraryY/build/libY.so
        ${libraries}/libraryZ/build/libZ.so
)
```

I am only interested in building/running one project (e.g. `projectA/`) at a time, but **I don't want to manually precompile every library every time** I make changes.

Also, I cannot move `libraries/` under the project (e.g. `projectA/libraries/libraryX`) because `projectB/` also depends on them, and I don't like having two clones of the same repository in one computer in sibling folders. I also cannot change and rearrange the content of repositories to suit myself, because different teams are working on them and plan to release them as full packages installable from apt-get in the future. Finally, I don't want to use a single top-level `CMakeLists.txt` inside the workspace because the projects A and B are independent from each other.

I tried looking into `add_subdirectory` and `target_sources` but could not understand how to target a source if I want the same library to be used by different executables in `projectA` and `projectB`.

Of course, I can run a bash script that builds cmakes in every library, but I thought that this is a job of CMake to do such things. I am clearly not seeing some obvious solution here.

Can anyone help me to force CMake to precompile the library before linking them to the target?

Thanks!

P.S. How can I tell CMake to compile `*.dll` files instead of `*.so`, and `*.exe` instead of Linux binaries?

I have read and watched a lot of tutorials and read a lot of stackoverflow answers about the architecture of the CMake projects. I tried to run the project in Visual Studio on Windows in hopes of it figuring it out itself -- didn't really help. I wrote a bash script that compiles libraries before linking them but it feels wrong, because I was promised that CMake actually does this thing for me. I also tried to use subdirectory system as mentioned in another stackoverflow answer but it did not really succeed.

Comment: I think that your problem could be solved with `add_subdirectory`, but you already tried. Can you share more details about what happens when you use this command?

Comment: @ViniciusAlmada when I am targeting a source from a subdirectory, I have to name a source but the source can be either `projectA/outA` or `projectB/outB`. So, whenever I use `libraryX` from `projectA` I have to edit CMakeFiles and vice versa. Or is it ok to name both executables as `out` an

Comment: I guess you need to set up a package repository like e.g. [Conan](https://github.com/conan-io/conan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `libraryX/CMakeLists.txt` would look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(libraryX LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(libX SHARED fileX.cpp)

target_include_directories(
    libX 
    PUBLIC 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
  )
```

At the root directory of all sub-projects, you may add the `CMakeLists.txt` which performs `add_subdirectory()` for all libraries (first) and binaries (last).

Then in the `projectX/CMakeLists.txt` just link to CMake targets you need:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(projectX LANGUAGES CXX)

add_executable(outA mainA.cpp)

target_include_directories(
    outA
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    # NOTE No need for any other paths
  )

target_link_libraries(
    outA
    PRIVATE
        libX
        libY
        libZ
  )
```

Update (after I spot that these are separate git repos):

You need to [export](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html#exporting-targets) your library targets (build and install 'em into the same prefix) and use `find_package(libX)` in your `projectX/CMakeLists.txt` to find a target to link with.
Having separate libs is nice (compared to a monorepo ;).

Comment: Thanks! Just adding the subdirectories without changing anything in the libraries, worked for me. Now, whenever I build a projectA it also builds all the added libraries!